# Could not find a kernel matching Python 3. Please select a kernel

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter-lab

After I tried to install and register a new virtual environment so I can use it in Jupyter notebook, I ended up with the following problem: any notebook I open or create it displays the error message: "Could not find a kernel matching Python 3. Please select a kernel:"
but there are no kernels registered anymore ...

I couldn't find a good answer although I noticed that many others faced the same problem in the past. Anyone could help?

I am using Ubuntu and pip.

It seems to be a configuration problem with Jupyter.

```
$ jupyter --paths --debug
JUPYTER_PREFER_ENV_PATH is not set, making the user-level path preferred over the environment-level path for data and config
JUPYTER_NO_CONFIG is not set, so we use the full path list for config
JUPYTER_CONFIG_PATH is not set, so we do not prepend anything to the config paths
JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR is not set, so we use the default user-level config directory
JUPYTER_PATH is not set, so we do not prepend anything to the data paths
JUPYTER_DATA_DIR is not set, so we use the default user-level data directory
JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR is not set, so we use the default runtime directory

config:
    /home/florian/.jupyter
    /home/florian/..../OCR/ocr_env/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /home/florian/.local/share/jupyter

 jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:

  ocr_env          /home/florian/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ocr_env
  python3          /home/florian/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  spark_env        /home/florian/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/spark_env
  tensorflow       /home/florian/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/tensorflow
```

Another error trying to upgrade pip:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import (
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
  File "/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_sysconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import InvalidSchemeCombination, UserInstallationInvalid
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSchemeCombination' from 'pip._internal.exceptions' (/home/florian/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py)
```

Comment: What does `$ which python` output from the terminal that you launched jupyter notebook from?

Comment: Answer to $which python: /home/.../OCR/ocr_env/bin/python

Comment: I believe it is a config file with jupyter. I saved above the printout to jupyter --debug.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found a solution like this below:

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall jupyter_client
```

Answer (score -1):

1. `julia> import Pkg; Pkg.add("IJulia")`
2. `julia> using IJulia`
3. `julia> IJulia.notebook`
4. ❤️

Reference:

- `julia>` is running julia.app on macOS
- https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/968#issuecomment-739800974